# How to execute this diagonal argument?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given is an infinite set $M_1 \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. We choose infinite subsets $M_n$ such that $M_{n+1} \subset M_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now we claim that $\lim_{n \to \infty} M_n =: M_{\infty}$ is also an infinite set which is contained by each $M_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. 
In my book is says that we argue with an diagonal argument but I don't know how to apply it in this situation.
Has anybody some hints or explaination?

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false. Suppose that, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, you define$$M_n=\{m\in\mathbb N\,:\,2^n\mid m\}.$$Then $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}M_n=\emptyset$. In particular, there is no infinite set contained in in each $M_n$.

Comment: Alternative choice: $M_n = \{m \in \mathbb{N}: m > n\}$

Comment: That would have been my choice if I had though about it. $\ddot\smile$